# Why does my ceiling fan spin the wrong way?

Tags: induction-motor, reverse-polarity

My ceiling fan blows are at the ceiling (uselessly).  At first, I wondered whether I could fix it by maybe removing it and switching some kind of polarity.  But is there a polarity?  Aren't the residential power wires live and ground?  How does the fan know which way to spin?

Comment: I believe that for some fans, it's possible to simply twist the blades so that the direction of air flow can be reversed without changing the direction the fan rotates.

Comment: Many ceiling fans have a switch to reverse direction.  The two ceiling fans I have can be switched.

Comment: The "up" direction is used to circulate warm air in the winter time.  You don't want a breeze blowing down on you, but you do want to move the warm air back down where you are.

Comment: Not sure which answer to accept.  I learned from all of them.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ceiling fan has a split-phase motor with a capacitor. The required direction of rotation is obtained by interchanging the 'Line' connection as shown.

[image]

Comment: So the line oscillates around zero?  What determines the direction?

Comment: The capacitor creates a phase shift on the winding with which it is in series. That creates enough of a delay that the windings reach maximum power at slightly differing times. This creates the rotating magnetic field which determines the direction of rotation.

Comment: Selecting the winding that goes in series with the capacitor determines the direction of rotation.

Comment: Okay, thanks both.  I can barely wrap my head around it, but I think I see it now.

Answer (score 3):

The fan would have a  capacitor to put phase shifted voltage to additional coil in the motor.

Sometimes there is a switch to change direction and it changes which way the motor runs, by changing which way the phase is shifted.

Residential power depends on where you live. Some have single phase only, some have two phase, and some have three phase. Nevertheless, a ceiling fan would usually have single phase and neutral return, and protective earth ground.

Comment: I thought that even if power is three phase, only one of the phases goes into a particular house?  Or sometimes two phases go in for high voltage appliances?  That's why I thought there was just one phase as far as the fan is concerned.

Comment: In the parts of the world I live, I have never seen other than houses powered with 3 phase mains and heating and stoves typically use 3 phase mains. Where you live things might be different. A ceiling fan should still use 1 phase only. It will generate it's own phase shift it needs with a capacitor.

Answer (score 2):

"Uselessly" is wrong.   If you want to circulate air, breaking up the hot layer near the ceiling, then either way will work.   If you want to sit underneath the fan and feel a breeze, then yes, it must direct air downwards.   But if you want the cooling, but don't want to blow papers off your desk, it needs to point upwards.   (When pointed upwards, air descends all around the walls of the room.)

Look up the part number?   These fans almost always have wiring for a 2-direction switch.  Sometimes there's a pull-chain for doing this.  With a very old fan, the pull-chain may be broken off.  That, or the 2-direction wires were never hooked up, and are buried in a junction-box in the ceiling (attic?) directly above the fan.